# SVN doesn't want to store permanent exceptions on some systems

Tags: ssl, svn, ssl-certificate, permissions

When running SVN UP against a server some of my ubuntu systems doesn't want to store a permanent exception. SVN output looks like this:

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://aaa.bbb.ccc.se:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: aaa.bbb.ccc.se
 - Valid: from Tue, 29 Sep 2009 18:58:06 GMT until Thu, 29 Sep 2011 18:58:06 GMT
 - Issuer: CA, yyy, sss, Somewhere, SE
 - Fingerprint: 21:f3:62:28:d2:61:48:d1:40:47:20:6a:f4:a8:c7:75:05:c9:11:c6 
(R)eject or accept (t)emporarily?
```

Normally I would expect the last line to be

```
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

I assume this is an access right problem somewhere, but I can't seem to figure out where.

The last few lines from strace are:

```
fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1892, ...}) = 0
fstat64(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1892, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6c41000
read(5, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 1892
_llseek(5, -28, [1864], SEEK_CUR)       = 0
read(5, "\nCET-1CEST,M3.5.0,M10.5.0/3\n", 4096) = 28
close(5)                                = 0
munmap(0xb6c41000, 4096)                = 0
lstat64("/home/pehrs/.subversion/auth/svn.ssl.server/d3b23fecd33cba74aff2290b03a87862", 0xbfe6e84c) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Before this there is about 200 calls to gettimeofday()

Can somebody help me figure out how to store the exception permanently, so I don't have to check the fingerprint everytime i pull from the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an incorrect access rights for the svn configuration.